# How to prevent a gridview to get focus?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have 2 grids. When user is doing edits in one grid, I want to disable the other grid from getting focus, or atleast other grid from changing its foccussed row.

Example:
Parent grid, children grid.

If user is making edit in children of particular parent. I want to prevent user from suddenly shifting focus to different parent row. how to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried to set your Parent Gridview to Enabled = false? This should prevent the control gaining focus.

Comment: I am using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid Actually I tried with Enabled and it works fine, only problem is that it gets too much grayed to be viewable. Can I just disable without changing the visual properties, so that user doesnt feel anything changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only ways you can prevent a control receiving focus is to change it's Enabled or Visible properties.

Simply changing the parent's Enabled property to "false" (e.g. for the CellBeginEdit) and then back to "true" (e.g. in the CellEndEdit event) will prevent the user from selecting a new parent row.

Comment: I am using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid   Actually I tried with Enabled and it works fine, only problem is that it gets too much grayed to be viewable. Can I just disable without changing the visual properties, so that user doesnt feel anything changed.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with that control. But the colour-changing of disabled controls is something people have complained about before.

The only solution I've heard is to manually change the BackgroundColor.

It looks like there's perhaps more options for this Gridview... have you looked at http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument755 ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this but thats how I would do it (just a concept so ignore if any property does not match):

Create a property called mode and then use enumeration to set it to Edit or None etc.

Suppose you have GridViewParent and GridViewChild. In the FocusedRow event of child grid, at the start of all code, set the value of mode to Edit and at the end of all code in the event set it to None.

Then in the FocusedRow event of parent grid check whether the mode value is edit or not, if it is edit then use e.Cancel or something to get out of the focused event of the parent.

Now if you let me know exactly which grid are you using I might send you the code.

Comment: I am using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid   Actually I tried with Enabled and it works fine, only problem is that it gets too much grayed to be viewable. Can I just disable without changing the visual properties, so that user doesnt feel anything changed.